# Некорректно обрабатываетс @RequestMapping (RequestMethod.POST)

Tags: java

Есть метод, который принимает кучу параметров
Напишу только часть его

```java
@RequestMapping(value = ("/registration"),
            params = {"login", "name", "password", "passwordRepeat", "gender", "region", "comment", "browser"},
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@RequestParam(name = "login") String login,
                               @RequestParam(name = "name") String name,
                               @RequestParam(name = "password") String password,
                               @RequestParam(name = "passwordRepeat") String passwordRepeat,
                               @RequestParam(name = "gender", required = false) String gender,
                               @RequestParam(name = "region") String region,
                               @RequestParam(name = "comment") String comment,
                               @RequestParam(name = "browser", required = false) String browser,
                               ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session) {
```

Параметры берутся из view.jsp
причем поле gender имеет тип "radio", поле browser "checkbox". Если я не передаю в post запрос остальные поля, код все равно нормально обрабатывается. Выдаются сообщения "заполните такие-то поля". Но если я не передаю эти два поля - выдается сразу эксепшн. Даже в метод не заходит. Добавил в @RequestParam required = false, не помогает. Причем не обычных сервлетах работает если,параметры не передаются в Post(заходят в метод как null), на DispatcherServlet в Spring никак.

Comment: какой эксепшен выдаёт? Или предлагаете нам угадать?

Comment: Resolver.logException Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "login, name, password, passwordRepeat, gender, region, comment, browser" not met for actual request parameters: login={}, name={}, password={}, passwordRepeat={}, region={DNR}, comment={}]

Comment: Разобрался сам )